# When creating a service by Google Cloud Run, a trigger run is not done

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

I created the django-sige-gestao-enterprise service by Google Cloud Run for a repository in Google Cloud Source that is mirrored from GitHub but no trigger run was done and I could not find how to run the trigger. I searched Google Cloud Build but there is no button to run.

The message i was presented with when I created the service through Google Cloud Run was: The trigger for this service was successfully created. To execute the trigger, you must send it to the repository.

Comment: Verifique se está selecionando o branch correto.

Comment: Make sure you are selecting the correct branch.

Answer (score 1):

I fail to understand what is your issue, mainly due to language.

[Cloud Build documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-manage-triggers) has a section on creation and management of triggers using GitHub, which I assume can fit your case.

Cloud Build is a service that executes your builds on Google Cloud Platform infrastructure. Cloud Build can import source code from Cloud Storage, Cloud Source Repositories, GitHub, or Bitbucket, execute a build to your specifications, and produce artifacts such as Docker containers or Java archives, so obviously there is no run button there.

To see how to create a Cloud Run service using a Cloud Build image you can follow [this quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/quickstart-deploy).

To attach the previously created Cloud Build trigger to a Cloud Run service, you can see [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/continuous-deployment-with-cloud-build#attach_existing_trigger_to_service).